# New indexes on table causing query timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a view that I've been querying via an Entity Framework query for years now without a problem.  Yesterday, for a different use of the data, I added a couple indexes to the underlying table, which ended up causing the query to timeout in the Entity Framework (but returned faster than before when running the query in SSMS).  The data model was generated through the "update model from database" functionality, and this app is using EF v4.  The view is just a self join on the single underlying table I mentioned above with a date restriction.  I confirmed that dropping the new indexes made the Entities query run without a problem again.

There were 2 solutions we found to get the Entity Framework query working again:

- Set the query timeout to 0 (but I don't like this solution)
- Add another index to the underlying table which specifically addresses the constraints of the Entity Framework query (obviously the better solution and arguably should be done anyway)

Why does adding a couple indexes to a table - which made the underlying query actually run faster when running directly in SSMS, but do not directly address the query being run - make Entities trip up like this?

Comment: A consequence of adding indexes is that any related plan caches will be flushed, if a subsequent run of the query produces a non-optimal plan you would see the classic "slow in my app fast in ssms" symptom - http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: you need to provide the full table definition + use sql sniffer to get the query EF is running + getting the query plan for before and after adding the index in order for us to provide an useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add a query hint: tell it to use the original index that worked well for you. Hints are controversial, so do some research and lots of testing. You might also look at the "other use" of the data: make sure the new queries aren't causing locking that's blocking the original use case.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2045/using-hints-to-test-sql-server-indexes/